# Why was this person killed?

Tags: 1899

At the end of the episode 2,

> Ada was killed by Daniel

What could be the motive?

Comment: Was she killed?

Comment: @Adamant what do you mean?

Comment: It's all a simulation. How do you know that anyone really has died?

Comment: @d33tah: Well, what was the purpose of her simulation persona getting killed?

Comment: It is implied in episode 2 that Daniel is the culprit, but from what we learn after, it is not clear he killed her. Since he remembers past loops, he knew she will die but someone may not have done it himself.